# Comment prints more than once

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've made a CMS following the tutorial by phpacademy on Youtube, and now I'm extending it by adding comments.

I got it to print the data from the database with the comments.

However, it prints it more than once.

Code:

**Article.php** (Where I print the articles)

```
<?php

include_once('includes/connection.php');
include_once('includes/article.php');
include_once('includes/comments.php');

$article = new Article;
$comment = new Comment;

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $data = $article->fetch_data($id);
    $comments = $comment->fetch_data($id);
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>CMS</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <a href="index.php" id="logo">CMS</a>

            <h4><?php echo $data['article_title']; ?> - <small>posted <?php echo date('l jS', $data['article_timestamp']); ?></small></h4>
            <div id="content">
                <p><?php echo $data['article_content'] ?></p>
            </div>
            <a href="index.php">&larr; Back</a><br>
            <div id="comments">
                <?php 

                foreach($comments as $comment){
                    ?>
                    <div class="comment">
                        <span class="poster">Posted <?php echo date('l jS', $comments['comment_timestamp'])." by ".$comments['poster_name']; ?></span>
                    <?php echo $comments['comment_content']; ?>

                    </div>
                <?php   
                }

                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</head>

<?php

}else{
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}

?>
```

**includes/Comments.php**:

```
<?php

class Comment{
    public function fetch_all(){
        global $pdo;

        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments");
        $query->execute();

        return $query->fetchAll();
    }

    public function fetch_data($post_id){
        global $pdo;
        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = ?");
        $query->bindValue(1, $post_id);
        $query->execute();

        return $query->fetch();
    }
}

?>
```

If you need more code, or me to explain my problem more in detail, just comment.

Comment: What do you mean "it prints more than once?"  Prints what more than once?  How many times do you expect *it* to print?

Comment: Prints duplicate comments presumably.

Comment: do you mean it prints comments with the same database `id` more than once? If so, how many times? It should be a unique amount per comment, which is a good starting point.

Comment: I want it to print the data of one comment once, but it prints 10 times instead.. The page where I run into the problem is here: http://mackhostmc.zapto.org/cms/article.php?id=4

Comment: Mackan, can you do a `print_r($comments)` after you set it.

Comment: I don;t see how you code could fetch more than one comment at a time (though it seems you want it to potentially fetch multiple comments for an article id).  This is because `fetch_data()` method will only fetch one row of data.

Comment: should this be fetcing `$post_id` instead? `$comments = $comment->fetch_data($id);`

Comment: Try changing `$comment2 = new Comment;` and `$comments = $comment2->fetch_data($id);`, in case there is a conflict with your `foreach` loop - I'd don't know php well enough to say for certain

Comment: @OGHaza Ok, I added print_r($comments); Now it's crazy..

Comment: The print_r was so I could see the number of records in $comments. It looks like just the 1

Comment: Yes, there is only one for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your `$comments` array contains what you think it contains.

Right now it contains an array for a single database row, presumably a row with 5 columns of data.

This is because `$comment->fetch_data($id)` will only fetch a single row of data from the database.  It is a poorly designed method.

As such `$comments` array looks something like this:

```
[
  0 => 'field 1 value',
  1 => 'field 2 value',
  ...
  4 => 'field 4 value',
 'field 1 name' => 'field 1 value',
  ...
  'field 5 name' => 'field 5 value'
]
```

Note it would have both numeric and associative indexes because you are using default PDO fetch mode (which is usually configured to fetch both numerical and associative index).

When you loop on `$comments` you are actually looping through these values and since you are trying to output data from `$comments` instead of l`$comment` which is locally defined for your loop. Because of this, you are actually accessing the associative keys in this `$comments` array.

What you want to do is to change your fetch method to fetch ALL rows in the DB result set. That might look like this:

```
public function fetch_data($post_id){
    global $pdo;
    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = ?");
    $query->bindValue(1, $post_id);
    $query->execute();

    $rows = array();
    while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    return $rows;    
}
```

And then you need to change the echo statements in your loops to actually echo from `$comment` (the local variable name defined for the loop) rather than `$comments`.

Comment: Nice spot `comments` vs `comment`

Comment: Wait, how would I do the foreach loop?!

Comment: @Mackan90095 see my answer to change your comments array and change the $comments variable inside your loop to $comment.

Comment: @Mackan90095 You don't need to change the loop definition at all. Within the loop however you just need to change variable references from `$comments` to `$comment`.

Comment: @Mackan90095 Actually as amaster507 noted, you also need to use a new name for local variable in loop so as to not overwrite previously existing `$comment` variable.  For something like `foreach($comments as $item)` along with `echo $item['comment_content']` and similar.

Comment: @MikeBrant That worked! Now, Ican finally continue on my developing!

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit how you retrieve your comments using your function:

```
public function fetch_data($post_id){
    global $pdo;
    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = ?");
    $query->bindValue(1, $post_id);
    $query->execute();

    return $query->fetch();
}
```

Should be something similar to:

```
public function fetch_data($post_id){
    global $pdo;
    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = ?");
    $query->bindValue(1, $post_id);
    $query->execute();
    $results = array();
    while($row = $query->fetch()){
        $results[] = $row;
    }
    return $query->fetch();
}
```

Then it should work right as you think it should

Your array previously was:

```
$comments = array(
    'comment_id' => '1',
    0 => '1',
    'poster_name' => 'Mackan90096',
    1 => 'Mackan90096',
    'comment_content' => 'Hi! This is a test comment!',
    2 => 'Hi! This is a test comment!',
    'comment_timestamp' => '1385144211',
    3 => '1385144211',
    'post_id' => '4',
    4 => '4'
);
```

And now it will be:

```
$comments = array(
    0 => array(
        'comment_id' => '1',
        0 => '1',
        'poster_name' => 'Mackan90096',
        1 => 'Mackan90096',
        'comment_content' => 'Hi! This is a test comment!',
        2 => 'Hi! This is a test comment!',
        'comment_timestamp' => '1385144211',
        3 => '1385144211',
        'post_id' => '4',
        4 => '4'
    )
);
```

**Note:** using `$comments as $comment` as your foreach parameter is not good because $comment then overwrites your `Comment` class variable for later use.